# Pass custom HTTP header from Windows Phone to ASMX service

Tags: web-services, windows-phone-7, asmx

**Problem:** Want to send a custom HTTP header from Windows Phone 7.1 app to ASMX service. The ASMX service is developed by different team.

**Solutions tried:** There are number of questions & answers on net for this, but nothing seem to work in our case.

Refered [HttpRequestMessageProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.httprequestmessageproperty.headers%28v=vs.110%29.aspx),
and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14621544/how-can-i-add-authorization-header-to-the-request-in-wcf).

**Client Side Code:**

```
 HttpRequestMessageProperty httpProps = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
 httpProps.SuppressEntityBody = false;
 httpProps.Headers["HeaderKey"] = "HeaderValue";
 OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = httpProps;
```

**Service Side Code:**

```
 public string GetHeaderValue()
 {
   var properties = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties;
   var property = properties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] as HttpRequestMessageProperty;
   string headerValue = property.Headers["HeaderKey"];
   return headerValue;
 }
```

The "HeaderKey" value is not available on service side. Can any one point us in right direction ? Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried naming your header key with "X-" prefix? (eg. httpProps.Headers["X-HeaderKey"] = "HeaderValue")

Comment: No, I haven't tried that. Let me check that as well. How does the keys with X- prefix get recognized ?

Comment: It was a naming convention which stated that non-standard header keys should begin with "X-"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, So after some hits and misses, the below code worked:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.GetValues("HeaderKey")[0];
```

The issue with using OperationContext was for ASMX the OperationContext.Current was null. In WCF service, the OperationContext.Current is available.

Thanks @user623396 for your time and efforts. Hope this helps someone out.

Comment: Marking this as answer since this helped solve our problem. Hope it solves of someone else.