# In case I did it wrong, is there a way to add Session Token that would not produce this error?

Tags: wcf, wcf-client

[image]In this example, I assign the session token to **[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization]**.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can try adding the following code on client-side:

```
using (MyServ.ServiceClient proxy = new MyServ.ServiceClient())
{
     using (new System.ServiceModel.OperationContextScope(proxy.InnerChannel))
     {
         MessageHeader head = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("Authorization", "http://yournamespace.com/v1", data);
         OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(head);
     }
}
```

And add this on server-side:

```
string  auth = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.
GetHeader<string>("Authorization", "http://mynamespace.com/v1");
```

Also [the article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080986/authorization-header-is-missing-in-http-request-using-wcf) may help you.